# How to input the content of a form as a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm creating a universal converter using HTML and JavaScript as a school project, and to convert two units of something, such as feet to miles, you first have to type what you want to convert into a form. Then, when the Confirm button is hit, [at this point, because you can't convert things yet] it's supposed to change the value of a span in HTML to what has been typed into the form.

Right now, though, when the button is clicked, no matter what is put into the form, the span's value always gets changed to "[object HTMLInputElement]".

The HTML and JavaScript are below.

HTML:

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="unit">
</form>
<br>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
<br>
<br>
    <h4>Pick two units of <span id="unitType">[?]</span> you want to convert.</h4>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("confirm").onclick = function() {
    var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit");
    var unitType = document.getElementById("unitType");
    unitType.innerHTML = unitInput;
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually getting the value of the text input when you use `document.getElementById('unit');`. That only gets the *element*. You need to get the value of the textbox like this:

```
var unitInput = document.getElementById('unit').value;
```

That will get the value of the textbox.

**References: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/textbox.value)**

Comment: Just a neighborly tip. You're rarely score credibility by citing w3schools here.

Answer (score 4):

You need the input's value. Change:

```
var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit");
```

to:

```
var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit").value;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6SpH2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 unitType.innerHTML = unitInput.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is the classy way to add events to HTML elements. Be aware that you may vulnerable to [`XSS`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) if you are injecting arbitrary user input into the DOM. Make sure to do proper input sanitation such as converting HTML to html special characters.

If you take a look at the `unitInput` variable via [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir) you can see the properties. Each one of those properties can be accessed via the dot notation. [`objectName.propertyName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```
var element   = document.getElementById('confirm');
// to verbosely answer your question, to get input value, 
// you need to get the value
// property of the element
var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit").value;
var unitType  = document.getElementById("unitType");
element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  unitType.innerHTML = escape(unitInput);
});
```

**The properties of an `INPUT` element. (chrome)**

```
input
accept: ""
accessKey: ""
align: ""
alt: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
autocomplete: ""
autofocus: false
baseURI: ""
checked: false
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList[0]
children: HTMLCollection[0]
classList: DOMTokenList
className: ""
clientHeight: 0
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 0
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap
defaultChecked: false
defaultValue: ""
dir: ""
dirName: ""
disabled: false
draggable: false
files: null
firstChild: null
firstElementChild: null
form: null
formAction: ""
formEnctype: ""
formMethod: ""
formNoValidate: false
formTarget: ""
height: 0
hidden: false
id: ""
incremental: false
indeterminate: false
innerHTML: ""
innerText: ""
isContentEditable: false
labels: NodeList[0]
lang: ""
lastChild: null
lastElementChild: null
list: null
localName: "input"
max: ""
maxLength: 524288
min: ""
multiple: false
name: ""
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "INPUT"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
offsetHeight: 0
offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: null
offsetTop: 0
offsetWidth: 0
onabort: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectstart: null
onshow: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwebkitspeechchange: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "<input>"
outerText: ""
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: null
parentNode: null
pattern: ""
placeholder: ""
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: null
previousSibling: null
readOnly: false
required: false
scrollHeight: 0
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 0
selectionDirection: "forward"
selectionEnd: 0
selectionStart: 0
size: 20
spellcheck: true
src: ""
step: ""
style: CSSStyleDeclaration
tabIndex: 0
tagName: "INPUT"
textContent: ""
title: ""
translate: true
type: "text"
useMap: ""
validationMessage: ""
validity: ValidityState
value: ""
valueAsDate: null
valueAsNumber: NaN
webkitEntries: Array[0]
webkitGrammar: false
webkitShadowRoot: null
webkitSpeech: false
webkitdirectory: false
webkitdropzone: ""
width: 0
willValidate: true
__proto__: HTMLInputElement
```

Comment: Although this does answer the question, it does so in a very convoluted manner. The OP did not want a whole new method of creating an event listener, all he wanted to know is why `unitInput` wasn't getting the value of the textbox.

Comment: I can read JavaScript, however, the change that the OP actually needs to make is buried deep inside your code block making this answer very confusing.

Comment: Showing all the properties of an HTML element would help him if he really wanted to learn how to access the properties of an HTML element. I think your down-vote is uncalled for, and you should reevaluate your decision.

Comment: I recommend that you place the fix to the OPs problem (changing to use the value property) at the top of your post to make it more accessible to the OP and any future viewers. If you put your explanation (which, by the way, is great) after that, your post will be very effective and I will consider an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

get **.value** from "unit"

```
document.getElementById("confirm").onclick = function() {
   var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit").value;
   var unitType = document.getElementById("unitType");
   unitType.innerHTML = unitInput;
};
```