# How to change the content of a span depending on the content of a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, html

**Universal Converter - question #2**

Question 1 - [How to input the content of a form as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419811/)

Hello again. I'm having some more trouble with my converter (see link.) I was wondering how I could change the content of a span depending on what was inside of a form (in this case, looking at the link, the form with the ID of "unit").

How it would work was, the span with the ID of invalidUnit would be called in a function, and the function would be used to change the content of the span to tell the user if the unit they input into the form is valid or not.

The HTML and JavaScript are below.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="unit">
</form>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
<br>
<br>
<h4>Pick two units of <span id="unitType">[?]</span> you want to convert.</h4>
<h5><span id="invalidUnit">[?]</span></h5>
```

JavaScript:

```
function invalidUnit() {
    var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit").value;
    var invalid = document.getElementById("invalidUnit");
    if (unitInput.value == "temperature") {
      invalid.innerHTML = ("temperature is a valid unit");
  }
}
```

So, how would I make this work? It seems like I have it right, but...

Comment: You've used `.value` twice, read your code more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
 var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit").value;
```

to this:

```
 var unitInput = document.getElementById("unit");
```

Also, I think you'll want to add `onClick="invalidUnit();"` to your button.

[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mogacabu/1/edit)

Comment: I did those things, but the span doesn't change

Comment: Wait. YOU ACTUALLY JUST GOT IT WRONG! I put "invalidUnit()" into the main function of things that happens when the button is clicked, and then it worked. I wonder why you got upvoted...